# Any document from Microsoft about the best practice of building Biztalk development environment?

Tags: biztalk

We have two Biztalk teams and we will setup a Biztalk development environment. There are two approaches.

1. Use All-in-one server to install Biztalk 2010 and SQL Server 2008 together and share to be used by two teams at the same time
2. Use two separate servers (physical or virtual server) to install Biztalk server+SQL Server on each server. Each team use its own server for development.

Any document from Microsoft about the best practice of building Biztalk development environment in the above situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've seen the official requirement and guidance for installing BizTalk Server 2010 on a single computer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559454.aspx

There is no specific guidance from Microsoft on setting up BizTalk for any particular requirement such as what  you describe, or any other.

The best approach for a BizTalk DEV setup is a **dedicated VM for each developer with the entire stack** installed, Windows, SQL Server, BizTalk Server, Visual Studio and any other components that are part of your app, such as SharePoint.

It is not practical to share a BizTalk system for Development because active developers will just get in each other way deploying, debugging etc.

It is also not practical to use a remote BizTalk computer (meaning separate from Visual Studio) because the Deploy option only works locally.

Basically, the guide for setting up a single computer is the best practice for DEV, even though they don't specify that.